# Part Identification - bricks with posts

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

I have two unusual lego pieces that came from a collection of used legos that mostly seem to date from the 1970's that I am unable to identify using LDraw's ldfind app. What are these parts, and if known, what sort of sets might they have come from?

The red one is a 2x6 plate with only two knobs on the top of the plate, with a triangular post with that is about three bricks tall with one knob on top of the post. The bottom of this brick says "Pat. pend" and has A and 1 designations.

The black one is a 2x4 brick that looks like a wheel brick with holes on the sides that might be for wheels, except on top there is a tall post and two short knobs. The bottom of this brick says "Pat. pend" and has E and 4 inside the circles. It sort of looks like a technic post, but thicker.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The black piece is part of a steering mechanism, part of *[377-2: Crane With Float Truck](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?S=377-2)*. Here [it is](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?P=799c800) on BrickLink.

---

[Like Windfire says](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/2890/3176), the red part is a direction switcher. You can see the switch on the side of [the battery car](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=x488c01pb03).

Comment: I had that crane set. I'd cry, but aside from nostalgia value, my lost childhood LEGO collection is a drop in the bucket compared to what I have now. :P

Comment: Nice work figuring it out! I recognize several other unusual parts in my collection such as the string wheel winch, odd shaped hinges and baseplates which makes me even more confident it's a correct match. :)

Answer (score 5):

The Red piece:
Bricklink number 3218
http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3218

4.5v direction switcher for trains.  Works with a long switch on the side of a special train brick that hits the triangular post, moves and then reverses the motor.

The black piece is still a mystery.

Comment: That would be fitting that it goes with a 4.5 volt train sets. There were some other assorted parts in the lot that also appear to potentially be the remnants of a motorized train set.