# Red 2x3 plate with triangle post part number?

Tags: part-identification

2x3 plate with a triangular post.  Found 2 in a bin with a1 and a2 on the bottom

[image: 2x3 plate with a triangular post. Found 2 in a bin with a1 and a2 on the bottom]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Part Identification - bricks with posts](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/part-identification-bricks-with-posts)

Answer (score 2):

These are train direction toggle posts from the old 4.5V train system. Part [3218 Train Direction Switch - 4.5V 2 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=549%20%E2%80%9C%E2%80%9D).

[image]