# Identify red triangle stick

Tags: part-identification

Help me to identify this part please.

[image: red 2x3 tile with 2 studs and triangular post]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Part Identification - bricks with posts](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/part-identification-bricks-with-posts)

Comment: Your question is also a duplicate of [this one](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10079/red-2x3-plate-with-triangle-post-part-number).

Answer (score 8):

That's [Train Direction Switch - 4.5V 2 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3218#T=C)