# Set to this brick

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Do you know this piece? I would like to know the number of this item to see the set.
[image: black pin brick]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Part Identification - bricks with posts](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/part-identification-bricks-with-posts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have never seen this piece before, but it seems like this is [Vehicle, Steering Gear](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=799c800#T=C). In case this is the right one, black colored one was available in [12 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=799c800&colorID=11&in=A).

[image]

Comment: You are correct. I have 3 of those 12 sets you linked and this is most definitely the steering gear. The cabin of the truck has a bottom and top plate with a hole. Beam goes through both and gets a standard 2x1 brick on top that can be twisted to turn the wheels.

Comment: Hi all thanks again! I have found the set and finished it. It was from the breakdown truck nr 382.